# How can I set a loading state on a specific element of an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a list of components coming out of an array of objects. See the code:

```
const SitesList = () => {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);

  const copySite = (site) => {
    setLoadingState(true);
    copySiteAction(site)
      .then(() => setLoadingState(false))
      .catch(() => setLoadingState(false));
  };

  return filterSites.map((s, i) => (
    <div>
      {!loadingState ? (
        <>
          <p>Site: {s.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => copySite(s)}>Copy Site</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <LoadingStateComponent />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

I want to show the component `<LoadingStateComponent />` only on the index/component when I click the `Copy Site` button. As it is right now, every time I click on that button, all of the components disappear, hence what I see is the `<LoadingStateComponent />` until `loadingState` is set to false.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is `filterSites` coming from? Is that a prop or a hard coded value?

Comment: You need to wrap the async call in `useEffect` and trigger it by e.g. loading state change. React assumes that your pure functional components are *pure, functional components*. If you violate the contract all bets are off.

Comment: Hi @jered so `filterSites` is the array coming from the backend. When the component mounts, I call an action which calls the API and `filterSites` is the response, hence the array of objects where I grab the data to render to information on the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having a single "loading" state value, you need one for each item in the array. So, you basically need a second array that's the same size as `filterSites` to track the state of each index. Or, perhaps a better way would be a simple map linking indices to their corresponding loading state, so that you don't even need to worry about creating an array of X size.

```
const SitesList = () => {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState({});

  const copySite = (site, index) => {
    setLoadingState({...loadingState, [index]: true});
    copySiteAction(site)
      .then(() => setLoadingState(oldLoadingState => ({...oldLoadingState, [index]: false})))
      .catch(() => setLoadingState(oldLoadingState => ({...oldLoadingState, [index]: false})));
  };

  return filterSites.map((s, i) => (
    <div>
      {!loadingState[i] ? (
        <>
          <p>Site: {s.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => copySite(s, i)}>Copy Site</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <LoadingStateComponent />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Comment: This is good but you still have the OP's unwrapped API call, see my answer/not answer.

Comment: I don't think you need a `useEffect` here. `useEffect` is useful for creating side effects, not responding to them. Setting state before and after an async call like this is fine IMO.

Comment: XHR requests *are* side-effects, and that function isn't passed in as props.

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not solve your problem, but it will solve other problems and its too long for a comment.

This:

```
const SitesList = () => {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);

  const copySite = (site) => {
    setLoadingState(true);
    copySiteAction(site)
      .then(() => setLoadingState(false))
      .catch(() => setLoadingState(false));
  };

  return filterSites.map((s, i) => (
    <div>
      {!loadingState ? (
        <>
          <p>Site: {s.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => copySite(s)}>Copy Site</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <LoadingStateComponent />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Needs to look more like this:

```
const SitesList = () => {
  const [loadingState, setLoadingState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadingState) {
      apiCall()
        .then(whatever)
        .catch(whatever)
        .finally(() => setLoadingState(false));
    }
  }, [loadingState]);

  return filterSites.map((s, i) => (
    <div key={s.id}> // Note the key
      {!loadingState ? (
        <>
          <p>Site: {s.name}</p>
          <button onClick={() => setLoadingState(true)}>Copy Site</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <LoadingStateComponent />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
```

React assumes that your pure functional component is a *pure function*. If you violate that assumption it is under no obligation to respect your side-effects or render them when you'd expect. You need to wrap any side-effects (like a xhr request) in a `useEffect` hook, and like all hooks it must be called *unconditionally*. The way I've written it the hook will be called every time loadingState changes and will make the call if it is true, you may need to tweak for your actual use case.

Additionally, items rendered from an array need a unique `key` prop, I'm assuming your sites have ids but you will need to figure out a way to generate one if not.

Comment: How is `apiCall()` going to know what action to take, or with what data? `loadingState` is just a boolean that does not give any useful information about what component was clicked on.

Comment: @jered you can set it to a usestate variable and clear it with a null to wait for the next click. It isn't meant to be a full fledged answer, but no wa it would fit in a comment.